# Cross app redirect in Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication, cross-application

I have design 2 web apps and use Forms Authetication for single sign on

Web A: contains a `Login.aspx` page

Web B: contains an `OK.aspx` page

when access `Ok.aspx` in Web B, it will redirect to `Login.aspx` in web A (it work well)

But the problem is when I log on successfully, I can't redirect to `Ok.aspx` in web B

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username,false);
```

It try to redirect to `Ok.aspx` in web A not web B

my `<authentication>` sections:

Web A:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="appNameAuth" 
           path="/" 
           loginUrl="login.aspx" 
           protection="All" 
           timeout="30" 
           enableCrossAppRedirects="true">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Web B:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="appNameAuth" 
           path="/" 
           loginUrl="webAdomain/login.aspx" 
           protection="All" 
           timeout="30" 
           enableCrossAppRedirects="true" >
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post `<authentication>` section from both applications?

Comment: Web A:    <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>

Comment: Web B:    <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="webAdomain/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>

Comment: Are the web apps on the same server and running inside the same IIS application pool? (I see you have "webAdomain" in the second example is why I ask)

Comment: @Raelshark:you are right. I running on the same server and running inside the same IIS application pool. WebAdomain is something like 10.22.33.22:8033. loginUrl in WebB is something like https:10.22.33.44:5555/Login.aspx. Because I want unauthenticated user will be redirect to Login Page in Web A

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by setting the machineKey values in each of your application's web.config files so that they match.

By 'match', I mean, remove the IsolateApps setting from each web.config (as this will do exactly what it says, and that's bad for what you're trying to do).

Next, you need to generate new values for the decryptionKey and validationKey (values that match the type you select...SHA1, etc), and copy them into each of your web.configs

voila! everything should work

Here's a link to a Microsoft article on the machineKey setting, for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx